# Ruby with Watir: Handling javascript popup window

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir, popupwindow

I have a problem with watir and javascript popup window

here's my test script

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.start "/url/"

    browser.link(:text, /Add New Blog/).wait_until_present
    browser.link(:text, /Add New Blog/).click

    // Here is where the javascript window popup
    window = browser.ie.Document.ParentWindow

    browser.window(:title, /Blog/) do
    browser.text_field(:id, /text title of Blog/).set 'Watir'
    browser.select_list(:id, /dropdownlist type/).select ("News")
    browser.button(:value, /Save/).click
    end
```

The problem is after **window popup shows**, it's unable to locate the element of the text_field in window **Blog**. I also have try this but it says that => `in 'window': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)`

```
browser.window(:title => "annoying popup").use do
  browser.button(:id => "close").click
end
```

Any solution? and btw Im using ruby 1.9.3.
Appreciate your help.TQ

Comment: Missing `.use` on `browser.window(:title, /Blog/) do`?  Perhaps `browser.window(:title, /Blog/).use do` instead.  Caveat: not sure what's going on here: `window = browser.ie.Document.ParentWindow`

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of Watir - 
watir-classic and watir-webdriver.
If possible/convenient you should use watir-webdriver because it is the future of browser automation and where all the development focus will be going forward.

Your code looks fine if you are using watir-webdriver. I have never used watir-classic, but it appears that it only supports initializing a window with a hash instead of multiple arguments. So maybe this will work for you if you need to use watir-classic:

`browser.window(title: /Blog/) { #execute block }`